# changed index file, then I want search data to change in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, refresh, reload, shared

Please understand, I can't speak English very well.

I have 3 servers. server1 make index file in NAS(Network Attached Storage), others two server used only search. and I use simple locktype in the solrconfig.xml.

```
<lockType>${solr.lock.type:simple}</lockType>
```

**If the index file is changed by the server1, I want the search contents of other servers will be changed.**
I set the index path of 3 servers all the same to the NAS.
**first way.**
I changed the index file on the server1, and used the reload URL to confirmed that the search contents of other server changed.

> reload URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:9577/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core_name

but, Sometimes errors occur!

```
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: core's path/data/index/write.lock
```

I get an error even when I call reload URL again.

and, I looked for **another way**.
I changed the index file on the server1, and used the commit or softCommit URL.
However, it didn't work. The search contents of other servers has not changed.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: If you're _really_ sure about other Solr instances not modifying the index (mount the index store as read only instead), you should be able to use `single` as the lock type for your read-only-nodes: _Use for special situations of a read-only index directory, or when there is no possibility of more than one process trying to modify the index (even sequentially). This type will protect against multiple cores within the same JVM attempting to access the same index. WARNING! If multiple Solr instances in different JVMs modify an index, this type will not protect against index corruption._

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html#locktype

Comment: I will do try, thanks :)